# Referencing Node.js on Server

Tags: javascript, node.js, module

I'm not understanding Node.js exactly. I'm trying to use it on a Volusion site (Windows server) with an API I need to connect to. The API has a require() statement right at the very beginning which is their Javascript client library.

Through documentation, I've determined how to set up on my computer through Terminal (Mac OS X) but do I need to set it up on my server in order to user 'require'. I basically need to understand how to use require() statements and Node.js on a server and none of it's making sense to me. Any direction would be great. Thank you.

Comment: What doesn't make sense to you exactly? Did you read the docs? http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_modules

Comment: @FaridNouriNeshat, I did read that. I think I was mistaken previously. Is Node.js just used for local applications on computers? It's not a web based technology?

Comment: Yes, by default it will read local files.

Comment: Ok I supposed I have to build an application around it then to work on the web? I'm obviously new to this but I'm started to figure it out.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by working on the web?

Comment: Well I was under the impression that with the API I'm using I could write some Javascript, scrape an XML page and then connect to their API and upload the information. In their documentation (http://developers.rjmetrics.com/libraries.html) all there is are lines of code that start with require() and which appear to be Node.js. I've never used Node.js and have always just used jQuery and AJAX to get these kinds of things done so I'm muddling through this process to figure out how to get it to what I want it to do (I don't mind, I like learning new things; I'm just not familiar yet)

Comment: I'm digging into some tutorials now...

Comment: I see what do you mean now. What you know is the Javascript that executes on the browser and you haev access to the html DOM, but in node.js it executes on node.js platform and you have access to operating system I/O. You can basically use node.js to write a server, or a script.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54097/discussion-between-mxmastamills-and-farid-nouri-neshat).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a JS file
2. Write JS in it

   - Use your `require` statement there
3. Run `node your.js` on the command line

Node will then execute your JS.

> I've determined how to set up on my computer through Terminal (Mac OS X) but do I need to set it up on my server in order to user 'require'.

Yes. You need Node installed on the computer you want to run it on.

Comment: Ok, so maybe I'm misunderstanding how to use the API. The documentation is here: http://developers.rjmetrics.com/getting_started.html . I suppose this means that I'm supposed to run this application from my computer? I think I mistakenly thought that this was a web based application. Does Node.js only work on local machines? Thanks for your help.

Comment: How could a piece of software "only work on local machines"? It isn't a web based application, it is a library. You could build a web based application around it.

Comment: Ok, yeah as you can tell I'm totally confused by it but this shed a lot of light on it. Thank you. I'll read up more on it now. This got me pointed in the right direction.